# Show/Hide href link on click on a button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, href

On a BUTTON click a detail page is generated.
I have a href link when click on it, it navigates in the page. 
But on page load there should be only the button (on Clicking it main page is generated) but the href link is also appearing.

I want on the page load there should be only one button by clicking on it href link should appear.
And should disappear when another button is clicked.

Scrip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#priorityC').hide();
        $('#perC').hide();
        });
    $('#btnAnalyse').click(function () {
        $('#priorityC').show();
        $('#perC').show();
    });
```

This is the button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAnalyse" runat="server" OnClick="btnAnalyse_Click"/>
```

This is the href link which i want to show only on the click of the above button:

```
<a href="Homepage.aspx#perC">Hourly Detailed Priority Representation</a>
<a name="priorityPer">
<div id="perC" class="center">
<asp:Label ID="lblDPTC" runat="server" Text="Detailed Percentage     representation of Ticket Count" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</div>
</a>
```

Its hiding on page load but not showing on button click.

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: Please share your Code

Comment: @SamudralaRamu check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAnalyse" runat="server" ImageUrl="image1.jpg" OnClick="btnAnalyse_Click"/>


<a href="Homepage.aspx#p" id="linkid" runat="server">Hourly Detailed Priority Representation</a>
<a name="priorityPer">
<div id="per" class="center">
<asp:Label ID="lblDPTC" runat="server" Text="Detailed Percentage     representation of Ticket Count" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</div>
</a>
```

and on your backend page( codepage.cs)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        linkid.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void btnAnalyse_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (linkid.Visible == false)
    {
        linkid.Visible = true;
    }
}

 protected void btnAnother_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     linkid.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: the linkid is not comming up in backend page

Comment: Copy and paste above both code. Check it. It is working fine for me. Build your project and use this code again. It should work.
protected void btnAnother_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) remember this is the another button name which will hide href. Set this button name accordingly.

Comment: <a href="Homepage.aspx#p" id="linkid" runat="server"> have you changed this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `href` link inside a div and using `Jquery`, you can hide and show the the div accordingly.

**Code snippet**

```
<script>
// On load hide the div
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#MYDIV').hide();
};

// call this function on button click to show/hide the link
function showHideLink(buttonName)
{
  if(buttonName=='blah')
  {
    $('#MYDIV').hide();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#MYDIV').show();
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Newbie to Jquery can you tell me which part to write where? Thanks :)

Comment: Check for if your click event is working properly or not, by using alert inside the click event or using debugger.

Comment: Click is not working. I have used alert inside the click event. Is it possible that the click event in asp.net and JQuery cant work together??

Comment: The code you have written is for HTML button ,as the button is your asp.net control, hence it is not working try `$("#<%=btnAnalyse.ClientID %>").click(function() {
alert('Asp Button Clicked');
});
});`

Answer (score 0):

**test.aspx**

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" id="AdminFaciliy" href="charts.html" runat="server">
   <i class="fas fa-fw fa-user">
</i>
```

**text.aspx.cs**

```
if (Utype.Trim().ToUpper()=="ADMIN"){               
  AdminFaciliy.Visible = true;
}
```